# Is returning the address of temporary an undefined behavior here?

Tags: c++, memory-management, undefined-behavior

Is this undefined behavior in c++?

```
#include <iostream>

const double& abs(const double& x){
    return x>0 ? x:-x;
}

int main () {

    double x = -10.0;
    double y = abs(x);

    std::cout << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`g++` does not like it:

```
mem.cpp: In function ‘const double& abs(const double&)’:
mem.cpp:4: warning: returning reference to temporary
```

and valgrind generates all sort of errors.

Comment: Why would you want to return a reference from that function?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin This is just a sample code snippet from a larger function that more or less does this.

Comment: But why are you passing doubles by reference? For primitive types, it's usually faster to pass by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The results of the ternary operator are a temporary, and will
cease to exist once you return from the function.